# Where is Heimskr's House?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a burglary mission that's targeting Heimskr's House in Whiterun.  However, the objective does not show up on the map.  I've pickpocketed Heimskr to get the key to his house, so I know it must exist somewhere.  Could somebody point me in the right direction?

There is one house not far from the Gildegreen tree that's been boarded up at least since the Stormcloak invasion, and cannot be entered.  Please tell me this isn't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like [that is it](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Heimskr%27s_House).  If you are on the PC there is hope!

> There is a bug involving a Thieves Guild quest you get when asking for extra work. If you have already participated in the quest Battle for Whiterun it becomes impossible to enter his house, this is due to the rubble situated in front of the door. This is problematic when given a quest to steal something from his house. On the PC this is fixable with the console using the setstage command. Another possibility is to type "coc WhiterunHeimskrsHouse" into the console, then you get teleported inside Heimskr's House. To get outside you can easily use the door of the house.

Another option is to download the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Unofficial_Skyrim_Patch)

Comment: Well, crap.  I wish Bethesda would get their act straight and roll out some patches.  I really love the game as it is, but a fully bug-fixed version would be at least five times more enjoyable!

Comment: Note however that you can return to Vex/Delvin (whichever gave the quest) and simply give up. They will be "disappointed," but you can just get another one from them immediately, which will hopefully be at a different location.

Comment: I completed all the stormcloak rebellion quests and then did this mission. With the PC console command to pop in his house, it did work but unfortunatly the ring is no longer on the chest. 

Comment: Cancelling the quest has zero consequences. To unlock all the upgrades, I would cancel all the quests that already have the special quest done to save time.  I have hundreds of "failed quests" in my quest log from this with no consequences.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent and/or fix [that bug](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44465/4797), install the [**Unofficial Skyrim Patch** (original / Legendary Edition - PC)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71214) / ([Special Edition - PC](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/266)) / [(PS4)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4073181) / [(Xbox One)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2947804). Its [related fix](https://www.afkmods.com/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Legendary%20Edition%20Patch%20Version%20History.html) (v1.1 - 2012-08-03):

> Thieves Guild radiant jobs will no longer select Heimskr's house as a target due to it being destroyed during the Battle of Whiterun.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the crucial USKP. Glad I won't be running into this one.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible to get in there without using anything fancy. Just get as close as you can in the rubble near the door and crouch; it should say "open door".

Comment: The dialogue comes up, however when the action button is pressed changes immediately to close door with no further response.